# Problema em questão Python Manipulação de String/Arquivo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ola pessoal sou novo aqui no site e estou em busca de uma solução para meu problema. Atualmente estou estudando Python 3 e ao tentar resolver essa questão fico com uma imagem de erro, irei colocar aqui meu código ate o atual momento e a mensagem de erro que recebo.

```
soma=0
media=0
while True:
    arq1=open('CADASTRO.txt','r')
    arq = arq1.readline()
    frase=arq.split(',')
    frasefinal=frase[2].split('\n')
    arq1.close()
    if (arq == ''):
        break
    if (arq != ''):
        s=int(frasefinal[0])
        soma= s + soma
        media+=1
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:*/Lista 1 de arquivo/questao9.py", line 5, in 
>       arq = arq1.readline()
>     File "C:*## Cabeçalhos ##\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 22, in decode
>       def decode(self, input, final=False):
>   KeyboardInterrupt

No caso estou tentando calcular a media de idade

Exemplo de linha que uso no 'CADASTRO.txt'

renato,masc,19

Comment: Poderia colocar a mensagem de erro por completa? E se você abrir e fechar o arquivo toda vez dentro do `while` você não lerá sempre a primeira linha do arquivo infinitamente?

Answer (score 2):

O `while True` é infinito e a cada iteração, ele abre o arquivo e lê a primeira linha dele. Só pararia se a primeira linha estivesse em branco por causa do `break`. Acho que não é isso o que você quer. Acho que o que você realmente quer é ler o arquivo linha a linha.

Além disso, é boa prática ler o arquivo usando o `with`, para garantir que ele seja sempre fechado de forma ordeira, mesmo que um erro ocorra na sua aplicação, sem que você precise chamar o `close()` explicitamente.

```
soma = 0
media = 0
with open('CADASTRO.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as arq:
    while True:
        linha = arq.readline()
        if linha == '': break
        frase = linha.split(',')
        frasefinal = frase[2].split('\n')
        s = int(frasefinal[0])
        soma = s + soma
        media += 1
```

E absorvendo a sugestão da [resposta do Louhan Vargas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400338/132), use o encoding UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Ao meu ver, isso está parecendo problema de encoding do seu arquivo.
Tente adicionar o parâmetro encoding utf-8 na sua linha 4.
Ficando assim:

```
arq1=open('CADASTRO.txt','r', encoding='utf-8')
```

Se puder mostrar os dados do arquivo txt seria melhor ;)

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi muito bem o que você quer fazer, mas o código que enviarei faz a média normalmente e você só terá que adaptar com loops infinitos (acho que o while True não é sua melhor opção), procure algo pra ler cada linha do arquivo (while True não da)

```
arq1 = open('CADASTRO.txt','r')
arq = arq1.readline()
frase = arq.split(',')
idade = int(frase[2])
if arq != '':
    soma += idade
    cont += 1
```

e pra calcular a média cria essa variável

```
media = soma / cont
```

Comment: Por que o `while True` não seria a melhor opção para definir um loop infinito?

Comment: Não sei se é isso que você quer, mas provavelmente você teria um arquivo com vários cadastros, correto? Se for assim você deveria percorrer e fazer o procedimento até o arquivo terminar e não infinitamente, por isso deveria fazer uma forma de ler quantas linhas tem no arquivo e fazer um For no intervalo desse número, se precisar de algo infinito realmente faz com o while True mas se for o que descrevi procure por isso.